# React native NFC card reader and beacon

Tags: react-native, nfc

Can I create react native app that will read card with NFC e.g. ISIC student card and then use NFC beacon in mobile phone? Exists any library for that? Is there any NFC card limitation?

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 2):

[react-native-nfc-manager](https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-manager), i used it before and it work fine.